# Redirect from https://example.com to https://www.example.com without a valid certificate on example.com

Tags: redirect, ssl, https, url-rewriting, iis-8

i want to redirect all traffic to https://www.sitename.com

example

http://sitename.com --> https://www.sitename.com

http://www.sitename.com --> https://www.sitename.com

https://sitename.com --> https://www.sitename.com

i am using these rules

```
<rule name="Redirect non-www OR non-https to https://www">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^sitename.com$" />
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.sitename.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
            </rule>
```

these work fine but only https://sitename.com  gives certificate error and does not redirect properly

https://sitename.com --> https://www.sitename.com

this does not work ?

i have set same certificate for both  https and https://www.

i get a Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN  for http://sitename.com which is understood

is there any way i could redirect before the SSL handshake is made ?

Comment: Massive, gaping, security hole if you could redirect before making the secure connection!

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way i could redirect before the SSL handshake is made ?

No. If the browser can't establish a secure connection, a redirect can't be made (Except an HSTS redirect http to https in some cases)

You need to get a certificate for sitename.com too if you want to make it work (you can have one certificate valid for the two domains)